# Save an array and return then wrap

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-store-apps

I am writing an application that saves an array of strings but I am having trouble because it has a lot of specifications and it seem very convoluted to me.

It needs to do this:

1. It has a size of 6.
2. If the array has more than 6 it will wrap around and substitute the first one and so on.
3. A string is to be saved on every iteration (full).
4. The thing is that it will have to iterate on different times. For example I will need it to save the variable, return, then it will go back get another value for the variable and save in the next slot, return, and so on. (Here is where the wrapping comes in)

Anybody have a suggestion?

```
string[] locations = {"", "", "", "", "", ""};
int locationCount = 0;

if (locationCount >= 6)
{
    locationCount = 0;
}

locations[locationCount] = full;
locationCount++;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (locations[i] == "")
    {
        if (locationString.Split('/').Length > 6)
        {
            locationString += locations[i] + "/";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to persist the data like you want you will have to work in some static variables, you won't be able to keep it all in your method.

Perhaps something like this could work for you:

```
public class Locations
{
    private static string[] _locations = {"", "", "", "", "", ""};

    private static int _currentLocation = 0;

    public static void Iterate(string data)
    {
        foreach(var item in data.split('/'))
        {
            _locations[_currentLocation++] = item;

            if(_currentLocation == 6)
            {
                //Save Data

                _currentLocation = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the localsettings to save the variables because it is a windows store app.